# Is there a way in Gmail API to include extra fields (e.g. subject, body) in the message list method?

Tags: gmail-api

The "Try it" part documentation allows me to play the API, and the field selector allow me to select a lot of fields, e.g. header, raw, etc. But none of them actually showed up when tried the API. The only thing I saw were still just the message ID and the thread ID.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

E.g. The following:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{user_id}/messages?**fields=messages(historyId%2Cid%2Cpayload%2Craw%2CsizeEstimate%2Csnippet%2CthreadId)**&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Returns:

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "146da54fe3dc089e",
   "threadId": "146da54fe3dc089e"
  },
  {
   "id": "146da41d9486982f",
   "threadId": "146da41d9486982f"
  },
  ...
}
```

But I would expect the extra fields requested are returned too.

Is there a way to get this working?
I know there is a separate method to get an individual message but like to get them batch if possible.

Comment: I think they expect you to get the individual data in separate requests...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

messages.list does not return much more than just the identifiers.  not sure what the field selector is but i don't believe it's used.

however you can use a batched message.get to then retrieve many messages at once in a second call:

A batch request consists of multiple API calls combined into one HTTP request. This section describes the batch syntax in detail; later, there's an example.

Note: A set of n requests batched together counts toward your usage limit as n requests, not as one request. The batch request is taken apart into a set of requests before processing.

From:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch

With the Gmail API and batch here're some sample code:

```
GTLBatchQuery *batchQuery = [GTLBatchQuery batchQuery];

[gmailMessageIds enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *messageId, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesGet];
    query.userId = self.account.email;
    query.identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llx", [messageId unsignedLongLongValue]];
    query.format = kGTLGmailFormatRaw;

    [batchQuery addQuery:query];
}];


[self.gmailService executeQuery:batchQuery completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLBatchResult *result, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *gmailMessages = result.successes.allValues; // This is an array of GTLGmailMessage objects
    ... 
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that! There seems to be one problem with this approach though. "Note: A set of n requests batched together counts toward your usage limit as n requests, not as one request. The batch request is taken apart into a set of requests before processing." Based on that by fetching 10 messages quickly (within 1 second) would have caused me to go over the 10 request per second limit.

Comment: Did you actually try it and go over the 10 requests/second limit or are you merely speculating?  I'd go and try it  before you speculate.  I don't believe that limit is applied at something as short as a 1 second granularity but rather average over a little bit longer window.  Feel free to reply if I'm wrong.

Comment: Fair enough. No I haven't tried the batch yet since I'm using iOS and there is no SDK yet for the gmail API. But I did try firing 50 requests asynchronously and it starts failing after ~10th. But I will try the batch and reply back.

Comment: Hi fatshu, iOs libraries can be found here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSource%2FServices%2FGmail%2FGenerated

Hopefully will get it sorted out to be linked from docs in next few hours.

Is 50 requests asynchronously and failing after ~10h unexpected?  I'm unclear what you're saying.  What request throughput are you maintaining (50/second?)?  What's the failure (e.g. 429)?

Comment: Thanks, I saw the library after I replied last night and is going to integrate with it now. I was firing 50 asynchronously and some of them started to timeout (as reported by NSURLConnection). I'm doing a default list on messages (which returns 50 on the first page) and I'm firing get of these messages all asynchronously. And I started to see the connection timeout. But that's as far as I could tell last night. Will check in again after I finish integrating with the SDK and do some more experiment.

Comment: Also note that now messages.get() and threads.get() both support format=METADATA and metadataHeaders=['from', 'to', 'subject', ...] params.  so when you do do the second batched get() call you can request just the things you need which should make it faster/more efficient (and we'll be updating quota soon to reflect that).

Answer (score 0):

Upon browsing the Google documentation, using the [messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) section, I was able to return all of the field values via json using the method `getMessage(...)`.

In the original request you are given the `id` and `threadId`. Using the id we are able to return all messages by doing something like so:

```
ListMessagesResponse mResponse =
            service.users().messages().list(user).execute();

// This will return the json listed with the field methods id and threadId.
List<Message> messages = mResponse.getMessages();

// Parse the response
if(message.size() == 0){...}
else {
  for(Message msg: messages)
    *.getMessage(service,user,msg.getId());
}
```

The above is not exact code but, should provide you with an idea of how to approach this problem.