# Efficiently getting read status gmail api

Tags: gmail-api

What is the most efficient way to get the emails "read status" after doing list of messages for some search query?

As mentioned in the [include extra field question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441433/is-there-a-way-in-gmail-api-to-include-extra-fields-e-g-subject-body-in-the) for messages#list there are field options in [Google's try api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it) but it doesn't return the results with those fields. May be this is a bug or gmail team didn't add these fields in response for efficiency reasons.

Assuming we can not get any extra fields including labels from messages#list api, what is the best way to get only read status for the list of messages obtained from messages#list api? I want to avoid loading anything other than read status which we get while using "minimal" from get api.

Comment: The functionality I am looking is similar to fetchprofile "FLAGS" while using IMAP#fetch which allows me to get labels/read status with the first search result so that its efficient as well as fewer API calls.

Comment: Not sure why a downvote in this question, it seems something everyone will encounter when they move to newer gmail API from original IMAP based search for gmails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need message.id and read/unread status you could do that without ever calling messages.get() and that would be most efficient.  Simply make two list() calls, one with "is:unread" and the other "is:read" and that'll provide the info you need.

Alternatively, if you need more than just read/unread status after doing a messages.list(), pass those message.ids to a (batched) messages.get() call with format=MINIMAL (or METADATA or whatnot).  You should be able to do that quite efficiently and quickly.

Comment: Thanks Eric. All I need for this is n (n=25 usually) most recent  emails for the search query and their read status.

Comment: For n=25, either way should work and be pretty quick.  I imagine two message.lists() will certainly scale better as N increases (as those type of label queries are indexed directly in the backend so even doing it for N=1000 should be fine).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing: 1. Get n messages with the query. 2. Get n messages with "is:read" and construct n with read status from set from step 1 and step 2.